# Make DHCP work while AirPort to AirPort bridging

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-access-point

I'm using an AirPort Extreme (1st gen) to my Mac Pro (via Ethernet cable) since there is no built-in AirPort support in this Mac Pro model. The AirPort is bridged to another AirPort (5th gen) via 2.4GHz and encrypted by WPA2. The second AirPort is connected to my ISP via cable.

The second AirPort is fully functional and all my devices receive an IP address and access to the internet.

The problem is that the Mac Pro only gets a self-assigned 169.254... address despite both AirPorts being in DHCP mode, as is the computer.

Why is the internet not working on my Mac Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Are both Airport Extremes using the same flavour of WiFi ~ I've been caught out with "old" AEs only having "b" and "g", not "n". Also check that the airport utility that you're using is OK — again my recollection is that one of the upgrades was a bit flaky. However I remember spending hours trying to sort out a similar situation with a friend's Desk Lamp iMac. In the end we gave up and treated the iMac to an airport card. There are some issues about running an airport express backwards.
Regards
Paul